# Ipad orientation change causes jquery to fire multiple functions

Tags: jquery, ipad, orientation

I'm working on a site that we're trying to optimize for ipad use. When you change orientation of the ipad to landscape parts of the site should hide to make it easier to read.
Everything works, but there when you change from portrait to landscape and back again, it seems to 'queue up' the previous jquery functions and run them one after another.

So if you change from 0 to 90 degrees it fires the 90 degree function. Change from 90 to 180 then it fires the 90 and 180 functions. Change from 180 to -90 and it fires the 90, 180 AND -90 functions.

Does anyone know why it's doing this and how to stop it?

-Edit-
The functions getting queued are the click events. This results in, when the button is clicked, the height of the targeted div rapidly increasing and decreasing like an accordion!

Code below:

```
jQuery(window).bind('orientationchange', function(e) {

          if(Math.abs(window.orientation) == 0){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'375px'});$('#top').animate({height:'445px'});$('#strap').animate({top:'445px'}, false);

              $("a.more-button").click(function(){
                  $('#slider').css({'height':'375px'});$('#top').css({'height':'445px'});$('#strap').css({'top':'445px'});
                  console.log('it fired 0');    
              });
              return false;
          }

          if(Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90){
            $("a.more-button").click(function(){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'0px'}); $('#top').animate({height:'130px'}); $('#strap').animate({top:'130px'}, false);
              console.log('it fired 90');   
            });

          $("#next-page").on("click", function(){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'375px'}); $('#top').animate({height:'445px'}); $('#strap').animate({top:'445px'}, false);
          });
          $("#prev-page").on("click", function(){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'375px'}); $('#top').animate({height:'445px'}); $('#strap').animate({top:'445px'}, false);
          });
          $(".menu-link").on("click", function(){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'375px'}); $('#top').animate({height:'445px'}); $('#strap').animate({top:'445px'}, false);
          });
          return false;
          }

          if(Math.abs(window.orientation) == -90){
              $("a.more-button").click(function(){
                  $('#slider').animate({height:'0px'}); $('#top').animate({height:'130px'}); $('#strap').animate({top:'130px'}, false);
                  console.log('it fired -90');  
              });

          $("#next-page").on("click", function(){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'375px'}); $('#top').animate({height:'445px'}); $('#strap').animate({top:'445px'}, false);
          });
          $("#prev-page").on("click", function(){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'375px'}); $('#top').animate({height:'445px'}); $('#strap').animate({top:'445px'}, false);
          });
          $(".menu-link").on("click", function(){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'375px'}); $('#top').animate({height:'445px'}); $('#strap').animate({top:'445px'}, false);
          });
          return false;
        }

          if(Math.abs(window.orientation) == 180){
              $('#slider').animate({height:'375px'});$('#top').animate({height:'445px'});$('#strap').animate({top:'445px'}, false);
              $("a.more-button").click(function(){
                  $('#slider').css({'height':'375px'});$('#top').css({'height':'445px'});$('#strap').css({'top':'445px'});
                  console.log('it fired 180');      
              });
              return false;
          }

  }, false);
```

-Edit-
The Solution! Following Simon's advice I've fixed the problem with a hybrid of his code and another user's (who didn't leave their name so I can't credit).

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
    screenOrientation = ($(window).width() > $(window).height())? 90 : 0;

    $("a.more-button, #next-page, #prev-page, .menu-link").off(".MyClickEvents");

    if (screenOrientation === 90) {
        $("a.more-button").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '0px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '130px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '130px' }, false);
            console.log('it fired 90');
        });

        $("#next-page").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
        $("#prev-page").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
        $(".menu-link").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
    } else {
      $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        console.log('portrait');
      $("a.more-button").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
          $('#slider').css({ 'height': '375px' }); $('#top').css({ 'height': '445px' }); $('#strap').css({ 'top': '445px' });
          console.log('it fired 0');
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: A user suggested that I insert 'jQuery(window).unbind('orientationchange').bind('orientationchange', function(e)' and see if that worked. Then he deleted his comment.
I can see the logic behind that but it didn't work; it still keeps queuing the functions. So frustrating!

Comment: What functions are getting queued? Those that are bound to a `click`-Event?

Comment: Here's an article I wrote last summer, it could help you adopt a simpler approach to this problem: [Cross-device, cross-browser portrait-landscape detection](http://pioul.fr/cross-device-cross-browser-portrait-landscape-detection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding your click event handler on every `orientationchange` so they get queued. Try to put your events in a namespace and unbind all events in this namespace on `orientationchange` before rebinding them. Her a simple example:

```
// assume these are the events bound to different some buttons
$('#foo').on('click.myNS', ...);
$('#bar').on('keyup.myNS', ...);
$('#baz').on('dblclick.myNS', ...);    

// magic occurs here...
$('#foo, #bar, #baz').off('.myNS');

// ...and afterwards, the three binds from above are gone
```

So in your case it would be:

```
jQuery(window).bind('orientationchange', function (e) {

    // First of all, we need to unbind previous events
    $("a.more-button, #next-page, #prev-page, .menu-link").off(".MyClickEvents");

    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) == 0) {
        $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);

        $("a.more-button").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').css({ 'height': '375px' }); $('#top').css({ 'height': '445px' }); $('#strap').css({ 'top': '445px' });
            console.log('it fired 0');
        });
        return false;
    }

    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90) {
        $("a.more-button").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '0px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '130px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '130px' }, false);
            console.log('it fired 90');
        });

        $("#next-page").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
        $("#prev-page").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
        $(".menu-link").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
        return false;
    }

    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) == -90) {
        $("a.more-button").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '0px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '130px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '130px' }, false);
            console.log('it fired -90');
        });

        $("#next-page").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
        $("#prev-page").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
        $(".menu-link").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        });
        return false;
    }

    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) == 180) {
        $('#slider').animate({ height: '375px' }); $('#top').animate({ height: '445px' }); $('#strap').animate({ top: '445px' }, false);
        $("a.more-button").on("click.MyClickEvents", function () {
            $('#slider').css({ 'height': '375px' }); $('#top').css({ 'height': '445px' }); $('#strap').css({ 'top': '445px' });
            console.log('it fired 180');
        });
        return false;
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in the code you posted would '.MyClickEvents' be the button I'm using to expand/ contract the div?

Comment: Ahm.. no, it's the namespace where your event handler are getting registrated. I added an example to my answer.